# Is a small proportion of higher gauge cable detrimental?

Tags: resistance, gauge

I have a monitor that takes 19.5 V, but I have been unable to find a barrel connector that matches the original with its 14 AWG cable. The closest I could find was an 18 AWG cable with matching barrel connector. (It's an LG 27up850w).

I have about 10 feet from my power source. My wire gauge calculator tells me I should use 14 AWG cable if it consumes about 10 A.

What is the *relative* problem / how bad would it be to have my cable be 99% 14 AWG and then splice in the 18 AWG cable and barrel connector for the last inch?

Comment: The 18-gauge will be about triple the resistance per unit length as the 14-gauge. So, using your 99% figure it would really be like having 97%, instead. (Or, like lengthening the cord by a little bit.) Probably would survive just fine. You are talking about under a milliOhm for the 18-guage if your figures are exact. (The issue is that the drift velocity will have to triple for that short length.)

Comment: Just one of those factoids (trivial pursuit things.) The drift velocity for 14-gauge would be about \$350\:\mu\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}\$ and for 18-gauge about \$900\:\mu\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}\$. The special theory of relativity won't interfere much here. :) Just one mm of length of 18-gauge copper wire has about \$10^{20}\$ conduction band electrons floating in it, ready to go. That's about 14 Coulombs. Plenty.

Comment: Does this monitor *really* consume approximately 200W or is that the output current capability of the power supply (or something else)?

Comment: You can usually get away with a short section of slightly narrower cabling. The connectors at the end and the heavier gauge wire will help carry heat away.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany fwiw, it offers a USB-C connection that not only provides video connection but _also_ charges the laptop at up to 96 watts, which I will use at all times :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 A isn't unusual for 18 AWG, in fact it's rated up to 16 A for chassis wiring (i.e. free air conditions), at least according to [one reference](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm).

14 AWG would be necessary for certain environments, such as in-wall, conduit, etc. use.  For chassis wiring, open cables, extension cords, etc., 16 or even 18 AWG wouldn't be unusual (consider how many 18 AWG mains power cords there are out there).  The voltage drop might be the bigger downside than temp rise, since you have a lot less to start with compared to mains.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This answers my concerns and is what I suspected as well.